# How can I run a command line command with a keyboard shortcut inside IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, build, gulp

I currently build my front-end with gulp from a terminal (I use mac). "gulp install" from a certain folder.

As simple as that is, I'd like to run this from inside IntelliJ. Preferably with a keyboard shortcut.

I can open the terminal inside IntelliJ and run it from there but that's not really any difference from running it in a separate terminal.

How can I assign this to a keyboard shortcut? Can I utilise the Run/Debug config in some way?

Comment: Came a bit closer by adding an alias to my ~/.profile, so I can run the gulp command from anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend creating an *External Tools* definition and then mapping that to a short cut (there is an `External Tools` section in the keymaps settings dialog). See the [External Tools](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/external-tools.html) and  [Configuring Third-Party Tools](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-third-party-tools.html) help pages.

Comment: I tried that a bit yesterday. Didn't get it to work properly though. But I think I should go at it again.

Answer (score 1):

In *Webstorm 9 EAP*, you can hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> (the default keymap for `Plug-ins -> Javascript Support -> Run Gulp task`) to bring a windows menu that list and can launch all your gulp tasks loaded from your gulpfile.

Here is an example screenshot for this:

[image: screenshot]

All the tasks you have launched will then be available in the run menu using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> (Linux).

See more on the *jetBrains* [blog entry](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/09/webstorm-9-eap-138-1988-meteor-support-gulp-and-more/) about this.

Comment: Gulp support seems not to have found it's way into IntelliJ, yet. I think I need to consider switching to WebStorm anytime soon...

Comment: If you plan to work with gulp a lot I think you may need to switch :/